# How to pad hyphen at left side : Oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sql-update, pad

I have existing records in the database the field description is

```
aa_desc NOT NULL VARCHAR2(8)
```

i have existing record for this field and now i have to add `- (hyphen)` with the existing record.

since it is restricted to eight characters i have to pad only the remaining characters with existing.

ex : if the existing value is `aaa` it needs to be padded like `-----aaa`.

how do i do this.

Technical environment :

```
DB : Oracle

Development : java
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Oracle's LPAD function. It adds the necessary character to the left side of the string to make of the specified lenght.So in your case, it should be:

```
LPAD(aa_desc, 8, '-')
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions095.htm#SQLRF00663

Comment: Thanks Guneli, update table set fieldName =  lpad(fieldName , 8, '-'  ) where matchingColumn=value.. ..